# Change VMWare resolution from 4:3 to 8:5 for widescreen

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

I have a widescreen (1280x800) resolution. When I run XP in VMWare, it cannot take widescreen resolution. It is just displaying in aspect ratio 4:3. How to change it to 8:5 (laptop screen).

Comment: 16:10  or 8:5  Res:1280x800!

Comment: oops, my bad, your right. It is a 16:10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you've installed the vmware tools you should be able to set the correct resolution inside the guest os. Just set the resolution as you would do in a normal Windows XP machine.